# how many logs required to get nextpageuri header?

Tags: logging, sharepoint, pagination, postman, response

I tried to get data from postman for Microsoft SharePoint. I gets up to 100 contentUri and generate 35,000+logs but I didn't get nextpageuri header.
I referred below site for pagination
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference
can anyone tell me when i get nextpageuri header?

Answer (score 0):

At least 200k logs in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).